Executing SQL script in server ERROR mysql
I have created an EER and want to forward eng it but i keep on recieving this error.this is the error massager the script for the sql
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
  CONSTRAINT `fk_artwork_artist`
    FOREIGN KEY (`artist_id`)
    REFERENCE...' at line 10
SQL Code:
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `a_work`.`artwork` (
          `artwork_id` INT NOT NULL,
          `title` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `year` YEAR(4) NOT NULL,
          `period` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
          `type` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
          `file` MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL,
          `artist_id` INT NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`artwork_id`),
          INDEX `fk_artwork_artist_idx` (`artist_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_artwork_artist`
            FOREIGN KEY (`artist_id`)
            REFERENCES `a_work`.`artist` (`artist_id`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 11 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch

I have try everything chatgpt reading the document that comes with mysql

Please run SELECT VERSION(); and report the result.

Looks like version issue - index visibility needs in 8+ version.

Try using the query below to create a table. It should look similar to what you want.
create table if not exists a_work.artwork (
    artwork_id int primary key,
    title varchar(45) not null,
    year year not null,
    period varchar(25) not null,
    type varchar(20) not null,
    file mediumblob not null,
    artist_id int not null references a_work.artist (artist_id)
);

You should create the index at the end because creating an index requires a deeper understanding.
This is taken from a MySQL reference.

Indexes are less important for queries on small tables, or big tables where report queries process most or all of the rows. When a query needs to access most of the rows, reading sequentially is faster than working through an index. Sequential reads minimize disk seeks, even if not all the rows are needed for the query. See Section 10.2.1.23, “Avoiding Full Table Scans” for details.


You should create the index at the end ??? The only requirement is the index must be created after each included columns creation.

Indexes will add overhead every time data is added or deleted. Indexes are not needed if data queries are already fast.

How does this fact is related to OP question?

I am just fixing the query made by the OP. I think the issue is only near the constraint.

OP needs to create foreign key. You remove it, and I doubt that this can be referred to as "fixing".

Check twice where I wrote foreign key, what the OP wrote only gives a name to the constraint.

If you disagree with what I wrote, let the OP decide whether my answer is helpful for them or not.
